# PODException: could not find driver

Tags: docker, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, laravel-9

Am running my Laravel 9 application in a docker container and am trying to deploy it on cloud run. The application need access to a database as it supports sign in registration and others. Am having problems in connect the cloud run container to SQL since all pages that require no database connection are working just fine, but pages that connect to the database are coming with an error that says could not find driver. I need help in identity where am getting it wrong or point me to a tutorial that best describes how to go about it.

I have initialized my app environments "dbusername, instanceunixsocker and the password
I also added the SQL instance of the database

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Double-check the spelling in your post title. Show the configuration of the container and applications. You are probably missing a driver such as `extension=pdo_mysql.so`

Comment: @ John Hanley found the problem I was missing the command to install the pdo_mysql in the Dockerfike